# checking cin input, clearing input buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, cin, typechecking

New to c++ - trying to check for format of input. Have tried everything, at wit's end. Any help would be appreciated. I've broken down my problem to this basic case:

```
while(1) {
    cin >> x;
    cout << "asked!" << endl;
    cin.ignore(1000, 'n');
}
```

will result in infinite loop of "asked!" after the first invalid input (entering not int for x). I want to handle incorrect input. The following will not work:

```
do {
    cin.clear();
    cin >> x >> y;
    if (cin.fail()) 
    {
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

} while (cin.fail());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `std::cin.clear()` immediately before `std::cin.ignore()` to clear the stream's error state, otherwise all future `cin` operations will exit/fail.  You can also test the success of `std::cin` operations more directly...

```
do {
    if (std::cin >> x >> y) break;
    std::cout << "Invalid input, please try again...\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} while (true);
```

Comment: cin.clear() is the first thing I do. Are you saying to do it elsewhere?

Comment: Yes... "alongside" as in both together after the failure, otherwise even `cin.ignore()` will fail.  Reworded a little to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked:

```
 do {
    if (cin >> customers >> chairs)
        break;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    }

} while (true);
```

thanks to Tony D